# Adjust font-size using a slider vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slider

I am using the following project: https://baianat.github.io/vuse/

This project is used for the end-user to reuses your Vue components as editable sections. It provides a styler overlay as a tool to adjust the content in a div or section. I installed a slider and it appears.

- I have the binding working [Click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cxd1.png)
- I see where the data is coming from [Click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tOlN.png)
- As an example, I can see how the `@click` loads the style [Click here
  to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuA46.png)
- This does not work just wanted to show the code I have been trying
  [Click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlNEH.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you get the value you want, save it as a reactive variable in your data object. Now you can use `:style` as style binding to adjust the font size for each element you want directly:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    fontSize: 12
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <input type="range" min="10" max="50" v-model="fontSize">
  <p :style="`font-size: ${fontSize}px`">font size: {{ fontSize }}px</p>
</div>
```

If you want a more global solution in your component, you can write a new class in the data object and declare it for each element with the adaptive font size.

The [offcial documentation got some examples](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1) for you.

Comment: I updated the property name from sliderValues to fontSize and I built 2 new functions 1 `fontSize: function () {
      this.executeFontSize('fontSize', this.fontSize)
    },` and ` executeFontSize (command, value = null) {
      this.el.focus();
      document.execCommand(command, false, value);
    }, ` It does update the font size, but it defaults to 7 and will not update like your sample it locks in at font-size 7

Comment: what does `this.executeFontSize` do? why do you have a `execCommand`? Is it because of `Vuse`? I have never worked with that before.

Comment: I tried to de-bug as far as I can tell it returns true. I changed the tool to accept an @click it does work to a point when the value goes above 7 it stops increasing. `li: button.styler-button(@click="fontSize--")
            VuseIcon(name='arrowLeft')
          li: input(type="number" min="1" max="50" v-model="fontSize").styler-input
          li: button.styler-button(@click="fontSize++")
            VuseIcon(name='arrowRight')` here is the code `executeFontSize (command, value = null) {
      this.el.focus();
      document.execCommand(command, false, value);
    },`